# Java - on Windows and Mac, how do you work out the network type?

Tags: java, windows, macos

I'm working on a Java application that runs on both Windows and Mac.  It communicates with various different servers but needs to behave differently depending whether it is using WiFi or a wired connection.

Is there anyway to work out which it is using?

I've looked at using `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` but that doesn't tell me which `NetworkInterface` is being used and whether it is WiFi or not.

Comment: Is the problem bandwidth? If yes, at launch time you may evaluate it to conclude: >250 MBps ==> network else WiFi

Comment: The problem is packet loss - the application uses UDP not TCP and I've found that the packet loss is much worse on Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this using native APIs.

- On Windows there's Native Wifi http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706556(v=vs.85).aspx
- And on Mac there's Core WLAN https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/CoreWLANFrameworkRef/_index.html

These can be interfaced to from Java using JNA. On Mac, you'll need to use something like https://github.com/shannah/Java-Objective-C-Bridge on top of JNA to use the Objective-C framework.

Answer (score 0):

With [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) you may execute `ipconfig /all` under Windows and `/sbin/ifconfig -a` under Linux (and Mac?) to answer the question "How am I connected to the network?".

To be more complete and accurate, you may enforce your protocol to add auto adaptive behavior: the quality, the bandwidth, the number of loss packets, and so on, allow you to decide how to drive your protocol.

You may use TCP/IP to drive the logic of the exchange (behavior, control) and use UDP for the data. First layer: UDP assumes discovery and data, second layer built on TCP to offer sessions management.